# Range checking fails for loading .txt files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, if-statement

I have been struggling to write the code to read in .txt data. I am in a directory where all of the file names are ‘img0001.txt’ through ‘img4200.txt’. Each file is a 2-D array of the same size (480x640), eventually I want to fill a 3-D data cube, but first I need to be able to read in all the data.

```
for i = 1:4200
    i
    if i<10
        A = csvread(['img000',num2str(i),'.txt']);
    elseif 10<=i<100
        A = csvread(['img00',num2str(i),'.txt']); ***
    elseif 100<=i<1000
        A = csvread(['img0',num2str(i),'.txt']);
    else i>=1000
        A = csvread(['img',num2str(i),'.txt']);
    end
end
```

The code prints `i=100`, and then gives me an error message for a file not found in the line where I added ***. The code is looking for file `img00100.txt` which does not exist, but I’m not sure why it is doing this.

I have been playing with different versions of writing the if, elseif, statements and the greater than and less than operators. I have also tried using eval and load commands.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure there are a several duplicates around, but try playing around with the [format spec](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html#inputarg_formatSpec) parameter. Specifically, `num2str(i,'%04d')`. Then you don't need `if/else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m7913d's answer explains your if statement's logic, but a nice way to avoid the confusion would be to **remove the if statements entirely** using [`sprintf`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec).

```
for i = 1:4200
    filenum = sprintf('%04d', i);               % Zero pads the number e.g. 59 => 0059
    disp(['i =', filenum])                      % Display current i 
    A = csvread(['img', filenum, '.txt']);      % Load CSV
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure how to zero pad the number. I'm still not sure on when to use an if-statement as opposed to a for loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if statements and for loops are for different things? If this answer resolves your issue, consider marking it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Your condition to check the range is wrong. You should write it as follows:

```
elseif 10 <= i && i < 100
```

What you calculated is the following (explained for `i == 100`):

`10 <= i < 100` <=> `(10 <= i) < 100` <=> `(1) < 100` <=> `1`

*Note that this is the case for a lot of programming languages (C++, java, js, ...).*